# Understanding anonymous classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand what this code actually means.

1. Why is all this code in a static block?
2. What is the wrapMapper doing?

   ```
   static{

       //new XStream inside static block
       xstream = new XStream(){

           // What is happening with the wrapMapper method?
           protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {

               return new MapperWrapper(next) {

                   public boolean shouldSerializeMember(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class definedIn, String fieldName) {
                       if ( definedIn != Object.class ) {
                           return super.shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName);
                       } else {
                           return false;
                       }    
                   }
               };
           }
       };

       xstream.processAnnotations(classA.class);
       xstream.processAnnotations(classB.class);
       xstream.processAnnotations(classC.class);
   }
   ```

Comment: The `static` block initializes static members in a class. It is executed only once. The `xstream` object is being initialized as an anonymous class, and is overriding the `wrapMapper` in the `XStream` class

Comment: Nathan Hughes, yes that seems to be my problem. I didn't have a term in my mind to look up. Now I know to read up on how to use anonymous classes and why.

Comment: I'll write a full answer with a better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

1. What is a static inializer?
2. What is an anonymous class?

The `static` block initializes static members in a class. It is executed only once. Here's a simple example of how this could be done in a basic class:

```
public class A {
    // we can initialize static members like this:
    private static Object someObject = new Object();

    // this still needs to be initialized:
    private static ArrayList<Integer> someList;

    static {
        // we can initialize it here:
        someList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        someList.add(1);
    }
}
```

This is generally used for static members that are collections of some sort, and require more configuring/setup than some other object (i.e., in our example, adding to the Collection).

[Anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), per the docs:

> allow you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.

They are generally used for an on-the-fly implementation of some interface of abstract class. For instance, say I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class NamedObject {
    abstract public String sayMyName();
}
```

Any non-abstract subclass of this object will have to implement `sayMyName()`. There are two ways we can do this (in this example). The first would be to create an actual subclass explicitly:

```
public final class Heisenberg extends NamedObject {
    @Override
    public String sayMyName() {
        return "Heisenberg";
    }
}
```

Sometimes we don't want to create an explicit class, and merely want to generate a once-off class that has the same functionality, but will never be used elsewhere. That's where we can use an anonymous class:

```
NamedObject anonymousObject = new NamedObject(){
    // we have to implement this method:
    @Override
    public String sayMyName() {
        return "We are Anonymous";
    }
}
```

Now, to your original question... The `xstream` variable is being initialized as an anonymous class. What you are seeing with the `wrapMapper` method is that the anonymous class is overriding the default `wrapMapper` method in the `XStream` class with its own functionality.  What's particularly interesting about your example is that the anonymous class actually creates yet *another* anonymous class within its `wrapMapper` method, which you can see in the `return new MapperWrapper` line, which overrides the `shouldSerializeMember` method.

**Personal opinion alert**: code like this is much more legible when you use the `@Override` annotation to explicitly document that you're overriding a super method. In cases like this, where there is no IDE syntax highlighting or context to the method, it makes it a lot easier for the reader to decipher what is going on! The code could be rewritten as follows and the reader would immediately understand what was happening:

```
xstream = new XStream(){

        @Override // we override the default behavior of this method
        protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
            return new MapperWrapper(next) {

                @Override // we override the default behavior of this method
                public boolean shouldSerializeMember(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class definedIn, String fieldName) {
                    if ( definedIn != Object.class ) {
                        return super.shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }    
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  That really clears it up!

Comment: Of course. If this solved your question, please mark it as the answer!